# How to read the output AND the return value of a external program in shell script?

Tags: shell, python-3.x, return-value, stdout, stderr

I'm making a script that reads a tracking code, looks at the results of posting the tracking to a website and prints some messages and has a return value.
Here's part of the python code:

```
# update return True if there was a change to the .msg file
def update(cod):
    msg = extract_msg(cod)
    if msg == 'ERROR':
        print('ERROR: invalid code\n')
        sys.exit(2)
    file = open('.msg', "r+")
    old_msg = file.read()
    if msg == old_msg:
        return False 
    else:
        print('Previous message: ' + old_msg)
        print('Latest message: ' + msg)
        file = overwrite(file, msg)
        file.close()
        return True

def main(argv):
    if len(argv) > 1:
        cod_rastr = argv[1]
    else:
    print("Error: no arg, no code\n")
    return -1
    # Verify if file exists
    if os.path.isfile(".msg") == False:
        arq = open('.msg', 'w')
        arq.close()
    # post() returns the source code of the resulting page of the posted code.
    cod = post(cod_rastr)
    if update(cod) == False:
        return 0
    else:
        print ('\n Message!\n')
        return 1
```

And here, I want to read not only the prints (for the final user) but the return values (for conditional use). This script should read the output of the .py and send me an email in case there is an update from the last check (I'll put this script in the crontab):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ]; then 
    echo usage: $0 CODE
    exit
fi

CODE=$1
STATUS=$(myscript.py $CODE 2>&1)
VAL=$?
FILE=$(<.msg)
# always prints 0 (zero)
echo $VAL
# I want to check for an existing update case
if [[ $STATUS == 'Message!' ]]
then
    echo $STATUS
    echo $FILE | mail myuser@mydomain.com -s '$CODE: Tracking status'
fi
```

The problem is that `$?` always returns `0`, and my string check inside the if, is not working, because I think It reads the update() prints too, which has variables in the print.
How can I make this shell script run, without changing the python script?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ...is that the entire python script? You don't seem do be running `main`. Does the script work standalone? Look into `sys.exit()` ...

Comment: not, as I mentioned, it's just a part of it, with the relevant code. I do run the main and the script needs the `requests` module.
What do you mean by looking into `sys.exit()`?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you can do what you want with the subprocess module.  Either use `rc = subprocess.call(...)` to get a return code while directing stdout to a file, or use `p = subprocess.Popen(...)` and then perhaps `p.communicate` to get output and `p.returncode` to get the returncode.